# How to aggregate transactional records by month year but based on subscription period not calendar months?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have a table containing transactional events for customers:

```
table: events
| id   | cust_id  | date                       | amount | 
|------|----------|----------------------------|--------| 
| 78   | 211      | 2010-06-18 20:10:00.000000 | 20     | 
| 84   | 211      | 2010-07-18 05:53:00.000000 | 35     | 
| 91   | 211      | 2010-07-27 05:45:00.000000 | 25     | 
| 2136 | 211      | 2011-02-14 20:07:00.000000 | 5000   | 
| 2947 | 211      | 2011-02-21 20:29:25.000000 | 22     | 
| 2945 | 211      | 2011-03-14 20:48:26.000000 | 22     |
```

I want to produce a year and month aggregation of the sum of the amounts, *but where the month periods correspond to the customer's subscription period.* This period has a specific start date, for example the 20th of the month.

The query can take the inputs:

- `customer id` - the customer to generate the report for
- `start day of period` - the day of the month on which the "month" should start

Here is a query that naively groups by month without the custom period:

```
SELECT
  extract(YEAR FROM date)  AS year,
  extract(MONTH FROM date) AS month,
  sum(amount)              AS amount
FROM events
WHERE cust_id = 211
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY year, month;
```

Example output of this naive query:

```
| year | month | amount | 
|------|-------|--------| 
| 2010 | 6     | 20     | 
| 2010 | 7     | 60     | 
| 2011 | 2     | 5022   | 
| 2011 | 3     | 22     |
```

But, given that start day for customer 211 is the 20th of the month, I want the actual output to be:

```
| year | month | amount | 
|------|-------|--------| 
| 2010 | 5     | 20     |  from May 20 - June 19
| 2010 | 6     | 35     |  from June 20 - July 19
| 2010 | 7     | 25     |  from July 20 - Aug 19
| 2011 | 1     | 5000   |  from Jan 20 - Feb 19
| 2011 | 2     | 44     |  from Feb 20 - March 19
```

I'm at a loss for how to go from my naive query to the query I need to generate this output.

Comment: Why does June 18 falls into the range of June 20 - July 19?

Comment: It shouldn't, instead it should fall into May 20 - June 19. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Does the start day vary from customer to customer? Or is it always the 20th?

Comment: It varies from customer to customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it calculates `month` according to next formula:

```
Month = If day < 20 then, if month = 1 then month = 12 else previous month
```

Obviously you can change day 20 by no matter which other day.

> NOTE: As far as I understand, this date `2010-06-18 20:10:00.000000` should 
>   returns `Month=5` due `Day=18`

> ```
> with calcMonth as
> (
>     SELECT extract(YEAR FROM date)  AS year,
>            case when extract(day from date) < 20 
>                 then (case when extract(MONTH FROM date) = 1
>                            then 12
>                            else extract(MONTH FROM date) - 1
>                       end)
>                 else extract(MONTH FROM date) 
>                 end AS month,
>             amount,
>             cust_id
>     FROM  events
> )
> SELECT year,
>        month,
>        sum(amount) AS amount
> FROM   calcMonth
> WHERE  cust_id = 211
> GROUP BY 1, 2
> ORDER BY year, month;
> ```
>
> ```
> year | month | amount
> :--- | :---- | -----:
> 2010 | 5     |     20
> 2010 | 6     |     35
> 2010 | 7     |     25
> 2011 | 1     |   5000
> 2011 | 2     |     44
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=bb78728f5685abb25a59aba69503d75c)*

These are values returned by CTE:

> ```
>     SELECT date as Date,
>            extract(YEAR FROM date)  AS Year,
>            extract(day from date) AS Day,
>            extract(MONTH FROM date) AS Month,
>            case when extract(day from date) < 20 
>                 then (case when extract(MONTH FROM date) = 1
>                            then 12
>                            else extract(MONTH FROM date) - 1
>                       end)
>                 else extract(MONTH FROM date) 
>                 end AS CalMonth,
>             Amount
>     FROM  events
> ```
>
> ```
> date                | year | day | month | calmonth | amount
> :------------------ | :--- | :-- | :---- | :------- | -----:
> 2010-06-18 20:10:00 | 2010 | 18  | 6     | 5        |     20
> 2010-07-18 05:53:00 | 2010 | 18  | 7     | 6        |     35
> 2010-07-27 05:45:00 | 2010 | 27  | 7     | 7        |     25
> 2011-02-14 20:07:00 | 2011 | 14  | 2     | 1        |   5000
> 2011-02-21 20:29:25 | 2011 | 21  | 2     | 2        |     22
> 2011-03-14 20:48:26 | 2011 | 14  | 3     | 2        |     22
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=22c7af810549d47c2218b87907e1cd64)*

Comment: Great! I will try this out, can you explain what the `if day = 1 then 12 else previous` bit means? Why 12?

Comment: Sorry, if Month=1 then Month=12, it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need something like this:

```
SELECT
  extract(YEAR FROM (date - '20 day'::interval))  AS year,
  extract(MONTH FROM (date - '20 day'::interval)) AS month,
  sum(amount)              AS amount
FROM events
WHERE cust_id = 211
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY year, month;
```